# Combinatorial Probability vs Binomial Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-distribution

**Problem:**

> A gardener has twelve identical looking tulip bulbs, of which eight
>   will produce yellow tulips and four will become pink. She randomly
>   selects and plants five of them and gives the rest away. When the
>   flowers start to bloom, what is the probability that exactly three of
>   them are yellow?

I first approached this problem using combinations: 
$\frac{\binom{8}{3}\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{12}{5}}=\frac{14}{33}$

Then, just for the heck of it, I attempted to solve the problem using 
binomial probability. I defined "success" to be planting a yellow flower and "failure" to be planting a pink flower.

$P(\text{success})=\frac{2}{3}$ and $P(\text{failure})=\frac{1}{3}$

$P(\text{3 successes in 5 trials}) = \binom{5}{3} (\frac{2}{3})^{3} (\frac{1}{3})^{2} = \frac{80}{243}$

I'm guessing one of the conditions for using the binomial distribution was violated?

1. The number of observations n is fixed.
2. Each observation is independent.
3. Each observation represents one of two outcomes ("success" or "failure").
4. The probability of "success" p is the same for each outcome.

None of these seem to be violated to me. Can someone clarify please?

Comment: Are you sure of independence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were correct to use the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) to solve the problem since the flower bulbs are selected without replacement.  The [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) is used when selections are made with replacement.  In particular, the probability of success must be the same for each outcome, which is not the case here since selecting a yellow flower changes the probability that the next flower you select is also yellow.